# Mongo DB - Group By and Having Implementation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to write a Mongo DB query where I do the following,

JSON list - Representing documents in my collection,

Industry[]:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57aa6058be0c853c8cee34cd"), 
    "options": {
        "paramList" : [
            {
                "name" : "industryCategory",
                "value" : "Travel",
                "mandatory" : true
            },
            {
                "name" : "someOtherThing",
                "value" : "dontMind",
                "mandatory" : true
            }
        ]
    }
    "mostRecent" : true
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57aa6058be0c853c8cee34cd"), 
    "options": {
        "paramList" : [
            {
                "name" : "industryCategory",
                "value" : "Dining",
                "mandatory" : true
            },
            {
                "name" : "someOtherThing",
                "value" : "dontMind",
                "mandatory" : true
            }
        ]
    }
    "mostRecent" : true
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57aa6058be0c853c8cee34cd"), 
    "options": {
        "paramList" : [
            {
                "name" : "industryCategory",
                "value" : "Travel",
                "mandatory" : true
            },
            {
                "name" : "someOtherThing",
                "value" : "dontMind",
                "mandatory" : true
            }
        ]
    }
    "mostRecent" : true
}
```

I'm trying to group and get a count of values for those paramList - values where name is industryCategory. Essentially, the output I am looking for is something like this,

```
Travel: 2
Dining: 1
```

I'm trying to do the following,

Industry is the name of the collection,

```
db.Industry.aggregate (
          [
            {$match: {mostRecent: true}},
            {$group: {
              _id: '$options.paramList.value', 
              count: {$sum: 1}
              }},
              {$match: {'options.paramList.name': 'industryCategory'}}

          ])
```

I'm getting an empty result. Please suggest what I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't have anyone answering. But, in the meanwhile I managed to figure it out myself. Posting the answer below,

```
aggregate (
          [
            {"$match": {mostRecent: true}},
            {"$unwind" : "$options.paramList"},
            {"$group" :
              {
                _id: "$options.paramList.value",
                count: {$sum : 1}
              }
            }
          ]
```

Essentially, use `unwind` wherever you have to iterate over arrays (a list of sub-documents). This has been a productive learning, at least for me.